# Polymorphism vector in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, polymorphism

I am trying to do a polymorphism in C++ language. My parent class is Person then there is a derived class called Student. Here is my Person.h and .cpp:

```
class Person
{
public:
Person(string name);
virtual void display() const;
string get_name() const;
void set_name(string name);
string get_birthDay() const;
void set_birthDay(string birthDay);
private:
string name;
string birthDay;
};
```

.cpp:

```
Person::Person(string name)
{
this->name = name;
}

string Person::get_name() const
{
return name;
}

void Person::set_name(string name)
{
this->name = name;
}

string Person::get_birthDay() const
{
return birthDay;
}

void Person::set_birthDay(string birthDay)
{
this->birthDay = birthDay;
}

void Person::display() const
{
cout << get_name() << " " << get_birthDay() << endl;
}
```

And this is my Student.h and .cpp:

```
class Student : public Person
{
public:
Student(string name, string major);
virtual void display() const;
string get_major() const;
void set_major(string major);
private:
string major;
};
```

.cpp:

```
Student::Student(string name, string major)
:Person(name)
{
this->major = major;
}

string Student::get_major() const
{
return major;
}

void Student::set_major(string major)
{
this->major = major;
}

void Student::display() const
{
cout << get_name() << " " << get_major() << endl;
}
```

All working perfectly until my main method. Here is my main method:

```
int main()
{
vector <Person*> person_list;
person_list.push_back(Student("Student","IT"));
person_list.push_back(Instructor("Instrructor", 2500));

for(int count=0; count< person_list.size(); count++)
{
    cout << person_list[count]->display() << endl;
}

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

I got an error at the push_back and cout there. The error message for push_back to vector is: no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list. As for the cout, no operator matches the operands. I have no idea why. Anybody can help me fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your **person_list** stores pointer but you pushed object instead:

To fix your issue:

```
person_list.push_back(new Student("Student","IT"));
                    //^^^^               
person_list.push_back(new Instructor("Instrructor", 2500));
```

To store pointer in STL container, better use smart pointer:

```
#include <memory>
std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Person>> person_list;
```

Comment: I've tried with this before but the error message is still the same

Comment: can I see Instructor constructor?

Comment: Instructor::Instructor(string name, float salary)
 :Person(name)
{
 this->salary = salary;
}

Comment: But currently our syllabus is only reached here. I need to make sure I understand this before move on to another stage

Comment: You added new in front of Instructor as well, as shown in my sample code?

Comment: Ya sure. I did this for another polymorphism which is Shape by using the same method and style and it shows no error. Very strange, only the student that line got an error but not the instructor

Answer (score 1):

You will need to push back a pointer to Student; i.e. use

`person_list.push_back(new Student("Student","IT"));` etc.

**But**, you will need to be very very careful with memory, since you will need to delete the memory you've allocated; the vector will **not** do this for you when it destructs.

Consider using a *smart pointer* instead.

Comment: @Gwen: "this does not solve it": what is the error message that you get on that particular line?

Comment: @Gwen Are you sure you're not compiling an old version of the file? It works for me: http://ideone.com/Q6nbTQ

Comment: what you mean by not compiling the old version of the file?

Comment: By accident compiling a version of your source that wasn't fixed. The changes proposed by Bathsheba combined with my answer do work. see the link.

Comment: Nevermind I will try to recreate and recode from scratch again. I'll get back to you later on

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << person_list[count]->display() << endl;
```

The `display()` function is of `void` return type. You cannot output that.

As for the `push_back`: like the others said, if you've got a vector of pointers, you need to push_back a pointer, not the object.